# can not determinate index in array

Tags: java, arraylist

Strings are added to the array, to determine whether the list is ordered by increasing the length of the string. If not, print the index of the first element that violates such ordering.
Everything works correctly if the strings in the array are different, for example, enter

```
113
13476
Neutral
wa
```

Answer: index (wa) 3 output.

but if it will be like this:

```
123
12345
123
```

Answer: index (123) - 0 but the correct answer is index 2

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            list.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(count+2 > list.size()) {
                break;
            }
            if(list.get(i+1).length() <= list.get(i).length()){
                System.out.println(list.indexOf(list.get(i+1)));
                          break;
            }
                       count = count + 1;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: and why is 0 not the correct response?

Comment: @Stultuske Because that one which violate the rule is on position 2.

Comment: The problem is because you use `indexOf` which will occur at first match. In your case at index 0. Why don't simply use  `System.out.println(i+1);` ?

Comment: And what should happen when Strings are equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change

```
list.indexOf(list.get(i+1))
```

to

```
i+1
```

since if there are multiple occurrences of the same `String` in the `List`, you want to return the index of the first element that violates the ordering, which is `i+1` (and not the index of the first `String` which is equal to that element).

BTW, even if there were no duplicate elements in your `List`, it would no sense to use `list.indexOf(list.get(i+1))` instead of simply `i+1`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `lastIndexOf` - you already have the index:

```
// Stsrt at index 1, as index 0 can never violate the rule:
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).length() < list.get(i - 1).length() {
        System.out.println("Rule violated at index " + i + " (" + list.get(i) + ")");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `PriorityQueue` and check within the supplied Comparator

```
PriorityQueue<String> p = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> {
      if (a.length() > b.length()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(a);
      }
      return 0;
    });

    p.add("foo");
    try {
      p.add("bar2");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      System.out.println(p.size());
    }
  }
```